# Bottom Navigation View covers MapboxMap - Android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, mapbox-android

I've tried a number of different things but can't get anything to fix this! No matter what I try, the map spills over to fill the whole screen, causing the nav bar to cover the attribution / bottom section of the map.

I thought it might be because I have set the layout_behaviour to hide on scroll, however removing that didn't fix the issue. Any suggestions are appreciated. :)

I want to keep the functionality to hide the nav bar because several other viewpager tabs are using it.

## Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/reading_tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/reading1_tab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Reading1" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/reading2_tab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Reading2" />

                <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/reading3_tab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Reading3" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <com.liftyourheads.dailyreadings.utils.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>



        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
            <!--app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"-->
            <!--app:layout_anchor="@+id/mainViewPager"-->

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

## Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.liftyourheads.dailyreadings.activities.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment_root_id">
    <!--android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"-->


    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/bibleMapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="40.73581"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="-73.99155"
        mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="@string/mapbox_style_custom_bible"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: can you post screenshot stating how it is and how do you want it to be?

Comment: you can use relative layout, and keep your map layout above of the bottom navigation. Means that placing your 'CustomViewPager' and the 'BottomNavigationView' inside a 'RelativeLayout', which in BottomNavigationView the ''layout_alignParentBottom" attribute is true, and the CustomViewPager is above of it. Going inside a fragment which you wanna hide the bottom bar, you can simply set the bottom navigation's visibility to 'GONE'.
let me know if the whole idea wasn't clear enough so I'll post an answer for you including the exact xml.

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been very clear! I want to keep the nav bar at the bottom, but not have the map continuing underneath it (ie. wrap the bottom of the map to the top of the nav bar. Not sure how to do this, however, as they're in seperate xml files??

Comment: Just following up on your idea Mohammed - can a relative layout be used with a child fragment? Ie. Can I open the fragment XML and alignParentBottom to an object in the activity XML??